# Changing the position of an android.graphics.Path on a canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, graphicspath

I've been browsing for some days now, but I can't seem to find a way to do this. I hope that maybe some of you are more experienced then I am with the Android SDK and its abilities :)

Say you draw the path on the canvas with the upper- and left-most control point x=300 and y=500 (the scribble in the image below). I want to be able to set the position of its "rectangle" to the canvas coordinates e.g. x=10 and y=10

[image]
So basically, it is the rectangle *with* the path that I am interested in. The idea is "cutting" this area out and moving it to a given position (but I don't want to include the underlying draws that are already on the canvas).

**What I have tried:**

Converting the Path into a [PathShape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/PathShape.html) and then a [ShapeDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html). I am able to skew the position of the Drawable, but it is too inexact to be used to position it.

```
ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new PathShape(path, getWidth(), getHeight());
sd.getPaint().set(p);           
sd.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

getWidth() and getHeight() are respectively getting the width and height of the *canvas*.

Can you please help me think of a way to do this by a new idea or by correcting my ShapeDrawable idea? Thank you very much for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Path transform](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#transform%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: +1, thank you for a quick answer :) I guess I was a bit lost at the Drawable, but this really helped. I found many guides where people use the Matrix for scaling and moving images in Android (which I can use for the Path).